# Export all environment variable from old eclipse to new eclipse

Tags: eclipse

**How to get all environment variable from old eclipse to new eclipse**

Example:

```
I was using JDK 8 with Eclipse Mars the we migrated our Projects to java 11 but Eclipse Mars doesn't support JDK 11.
So I downloaded the latest version of eclipse and now I wanted to get all the environment variables that I set for my spring-boot projects in Eclipse Mars. Is there a way for this in eclipse?
```

Comment: Why are you referring to this as an example? How were the variables set in the old release?

Comment: I was refering this example becoz, Envitonment Variables are many and Variables are set in "Run Configuration --> Maven-->Enviroment Tab. Which If I do not get an option in eclipse then I'll have to add all  of them freshely in New Eclipse, Instead I am seeking for like export & import option.